# Using a div as a background - responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, background, css-position

I'm sure there's probably a much better way to do this but I am trying to attach another div with a background image [with specific and exact line designs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a5Sz.png) as a background to these rounded rectangles. I of course was able to do this with position: absolute and z-index but this doesn't hold up on screen resizing. 
Is there anyway to attach the div background so that it shrinks the same amount and remains in the same position when the screen is resized? 
Or do I have to manually reposition and resize on as many screen sizes?
Thank you so much in advance.

```
.clientbackground {
display: flex;
position: absolute;
background-image: url(../images/yellowl.png);
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 48vmax;
width: 47.5%;
top: 6%;
right: 8%;
```

}

```
html

<div class="container">
<div class="clients">
<div class="clienttext">
<h1>CLIENTS</h1>
<div id="clientborder"></div>
<p>text<br>
</p>

</div>  
<div class="clientcontent">
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
<div class="rectangle"><img src="" title=""></div>
</div>
<div class="clientbackground"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet with the code you're working with (html and css). Thanks

Comment: done! For the desktop the div containing rectangles will show on the right side of the page, for ipad I want it under the title and text description :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my answer after conversations with you and understanding your requirement.

You have to update your HTML and CSS.

For this type of layout, you have to use pseudo elements means `:after` and `: before`, also you have to use `nth` ideology for making this layout.

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }

.outer { padding:60px; background: #32d2b0;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32d2b0 0%, #26aad2 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32d2b0 0%,#26aad2 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32d2b0 0%,#26aad2 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#32d2b0', endColorstr='#26aad2',GradientType=0 ); }
.clientcontent { margin:0 -15px; }
.item { width:33.3333%; padding:0 15px; float:left; box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; }
.rectangle { background:#FB9999; height:64px; margin-bottom:30px; border-radius:5px; position:relative; z-index:5;}
.rectangle:after { background:#E9E502; content:""; position:absolute; top:50%; left:100%; height:6px; width:30px; margin-top:-3px; }
.item:nth-child(3n+3) .rectangle { /*background:black;*/ }
.item:nth-child(3n+3) .rectangle:after { background:rgba(0,0,0,0); border:6px solid #E9E502; border-left:none; height:88px; width:30px; border-radius:0 5px 5px 0; z-index:1; }

.item:nth-child(3n+1) .rectangle { /*background:blue;*/ }
.item:nth-child(3n+1) .rectangle:before { content:""; position:absolute; top:50%; right:100%; margin-top:-3px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0); border:6px solid #E9E502; border-right:none; height:88px; width:30px; border-radius:5px 0 0 5px; z-index:1; }
.item:nth-child(6n+6) .rectangle:after,
.item:nth-child(6n+1) .rectangle:before,
.item:nth-last-child(3) .rectangle:before{ display:none; }
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
 <div class="clientcontent">
    <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
    </div>
 </div>
   </div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for answering! I'm sorry I didn't explain it properly. But if you look at the image I uploaded https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a5Sz.png , I want that div containing the rectangles on the right side of the page. The left will contain the header, etc. Added the html I'm working with up there! Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi @nica, i still dont understand what you want in background. In the layout, there are strings connected to boxes you want them in background?

Comment: yes! but if i make slight resizes on the screen, those lines aren't in the right place anymore

Comment: You know make it by using Pure CSS without using images because the design have basic color and gradients.

Comment: I don't really know how to make the yellow design by css. :o Any help?